# Use word(s) to select a whole line but not if one or more other words or patterns are present

Tags: java, regex

I have a table with a number of columns. One column is a free text field i.e. no set structure but I can provide order by looking at the keywords, writing a Regex to select the whole line and replacing the line with a simpler/better description. The 4 lines below are actual data.

```
************************************************************************
INVOICE·DID·NOT·MATCH·QUOTE·NEED·TO·DO·A·PARTIAL·CREDIT,·ALSO·NEED·TO·CREDIT·SHIPPING·CRATES·AND·REBILL·ON·A·SEPARATE·INVOICE
*************************************************************************
LUBRIZOL·RECEIVED·4·DV·THAT·BELONGED·TO·EXXON.·THEY·DID·NOT·RECEIVE·THE·CORRECT·VALVES·WE·CONTACTED·EXXON·TO·SEE·IF·THEY·COULD·F
*************************************************************************
MIL·SPEC·EPCC·SN:·000727·DID·NOT·ENERGIZE·WHEN·24V·WAS·APPLIED·PO·4500432166·DELIVERY·80794321·ORDER·498282
**************************************************************************
MISCOMMUNICATION·WITH·CUSTOMER·ABOUT·ORINGS.·THE·ONES·QUOTED·AND·SHIPPED·WERE·MADE·OUT·OF·SPECIAL·MATERIAL,·CUSTOMER·DID·NOT·NE
***************************************************************************
```

1. All of the lines contain "**DID NOT**"
2. One line contains the word "**CUSTOMER**"

**OBJECTIVE:** I want to find and all lines that contain "DID NOT" and then de-select the ENTIRE line that contains "CUSTOMER" leaving me with just three lines.

I've got a ton of lines to clean and changing the selection and de-selection keywords will give me a great deal of capability with this data cleaning effort.

The following REGEX line will find and select any line with "DID NOT".

```
.*(?=.*?\bDID NOT.*\b).*
```

NOTE: There are 2 asterisks (one at the beginning after the period and one at the end) that get clipped out with this editor.

How do I modify this line to achieve the objective above?

Comment: Add a negative look-ahead to the beginning of the regex: `(?!.*?\bCAT\b)` --- Matches if the string doesn't contain the word `CAT`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you might be designing an expression similar to:

```
^(?!.*\b(?:cat|dog)\b)(?=.*\b(?:thread|screw|bolt|tooling|machin|workman|incompl|craftsman|tolera|incorrec|too\s+wide|assembly|lathe)\S*\b).*$
```

or maybe something somewhat close to that.

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ErC8AU/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "^(?!.*(cat|dog))(?=.*\\b(?:thread|screw|bolt|tooling|machin|workman|incompl|craftsman|tolera|incorrec|too\\s+wide|assembly|lathe)\\S*\\b).*$";
final String string = "thread\n"
     + "threads\n"
     + "nothread \n"
     + "screw\n"
     + "screws\n"
     + "some words before tooling\n"
     + "som words before machines DOG\n"
     + "noworkman\n"
     + "non-incomplete\n"
     + "too   wide something after that\n"
     + "lathe some words after CAT\n"
     + "NOTincorrect";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Emma - jex.im is very cool I'll need explore that tool some more. The picture shows that it looks for "CAT" and "DOG" at the beginningof the line. I'm looking to de-select/ignore the line that is matched if "CAT" or "DOG" appear anywhere in the line.

Comment: @Emma...I'm having weird internet connectivity and I can't test your or SIN's solution. I will give it a try tomorrow when things behave better.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the line of this

`(?m)^(?!.*(?:CAT|DOG))(?=.*\b(?:ASSEMBLY|BOLT|CRAFTSMAN|INCO(?:MPL|RREC)|LATHE|MACHIN|SCREW|T(?:HREAD|O(?:LERA|O(?:[ ]WIDE|LING)))|WORKMAN).*\b).*$`

I don't have data to test it on, oh well ..

Explained

```
 (?m)                          # Multi-line mode if not already     
 ^                             # BOL
 (?!
      .* 
      (?: CAT | DOG )               # No CAT or DOG
 )
 (?=                           # Must have one of these keywords
      .* \b 
      (?:                           # Trie of keywords
           ASSEMBLY
        |  BOLT
        |  CRAFTSMAN
        |  INCO
           (?: MPL | RREC )
        |  LATHE
        |  MACHIN
        |  SCREW
        |  T
           (?:
                HREAD
             |  O
                (?:
                     LERA
                  |  O
                     (?: [ ] WIDE | LING )
                )
           )
        |  WORKMAN

      )
      .* \b 
 )
 .*                            # Have a keyword, just grab the line
 $                             # EOL
```

Comment: @SIN- here is an example of a line that I'm interested in: ----- One Clearance Pocket Valve was returned to customer before piston rings were installed in the outer piston. Clearance Ring measured.------ Several lines get captured with the keywords PISTON and VALVE but because the word RINGS is included in this line, it ,must be excluded i.e NOT selected. The kill word can be anywhere in the line.

Comment: @Kevin - Is there a problem reading the regex in my answer ? I don't understand your question... Adding new words is up to you, and it deviates from your original post!

Comment: @SIN - I need to check your reply to see if I get what I'm after. My internet resources are spotty at the moment as I'm on the road.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to match lines that contain "DID NOT", but don't contain "CUSTOMER":

```
^(?!.*CUSTOMER).*DID NOT.*$
```

`(?!.*CUSTOMER)` is a *negative look ahead*, which when anchored to start `^`, won't match the line if it contains "CUSTOMER" anywhere in it.